# Install 'yum' in Centos7

Tags: makefile, installation, centos7, yum

I've deleted **yum** from my server and I did wget to download **yum** again and extract it. In this folder, I have a lot of files:

```
AUTHORS      completion-helper.py  Makefile   shell.py  yumcommands.py
bin          COPYING               output.py  test      yum-cron
callback.py  docs                  po         TODO      yummain.py
ChangeLog    etc                   README     utils.py  yum.spec
cli.py       INSTALL               rpmUtils   yum       yum-updatesd.py
```

How can I install it?

Comment: I presume you've read the INSTALL file?  Is there an instruction within that is unclear?

Comment: How did you go about to remove it?

Comment: `wget ftp://mirror.switch.ch/pool/4/mirror/centos/7.4.1708/os/x86_64/Packages/yum-3.4.3-154.el7.centos.noarch.rpm` then `rpm -ivh yum-3.4.3-154.el7.centos.noarch.rpm` should reinstall the rpm

Comment: The link in above comment is dead, here's the latest valid one:   
`wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/yum-3.4.3-168.el7.centos.noarch.rpm  
rpm -ivh yum-3.4.3-168.el7.centos.noarch.rpm`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to install packages is to use the **RPM** command. You first need to download the rpm file and then install it.
For more infos: [RPM man page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/8/rpm/)

So, to install **yum**, simply run those two commands:

```
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/epel-release-7-14.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh yum-3.4.3-154.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: this link is dead remove it or update it thanks